# Why is there a large gap between two divs on this site?

Tags: css, html

On `http://www.gelcreative.co.uk/ightham/`, why is there such a large gap between the end of my content div and my footer div? There is no visible padding or margin, and I can't work out what's forcing the gap.

It's between the end of the white content area and the footer. Footer text should be much closer to the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You move your #contentWraper by using

```
position: relative;
top: -69px;
```

and you need to do the same for your footer.

If you use

```
margin-top: -69px;
```

instead, your footer will be positioned correctly automatically.